# Synchronous execution of mongoose queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

im pretty new to node.js/mongoose and i run into some difficulties getting my code to work as intended. Basically i have an Array holding some id's in a sorted order and i want to check against my Reservations if they hold those id's on a certain condition (same reservation date, time slot, etc.)

I cant seem to get my logic to work that basically should take following approach: Run through the table array from index 0 to index length-1, for each index there should be a findOne({]) query, if no reservation exists with that table id, a reservation shall be placed and exit the loop, if a reservation exists go to the next index and repeat until the array is iterated through from 0...n (the specific order the array is sorted in is important here, it should always prefer the least matching). If no table id is "free" to make a new reservation it should send a response message that every table is reserved already. Anyone that could help me out on my problem? Would appreciate any hints!

```js
app.post('/api/reservations', (req, res) => {
  const resDate = new Date(req.body.reservationDate).toISOString();
  const queryDate = new Date(req.body.reservationDate);
  const tableDict = req.body.tableDict;
  const slot = req.body.timeSlot;
  const seats = req.body.seats;
  const restaurant = req.body.restaurant;
  const customer = req.body.customer;
  const comment = req.body.comment;

  function gteQueryDate(date) {
    return date.toISOString();
  }

  function lteQueryDate(date) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    return date.toISOString();
  }

  const gteDate = gteQueryDate(queryDate);
  const lteDate = lteQueryDate(queryDate);

  const sortedTables = [];
  for (i = 0; i < tableDict[slot].length - 1; i++) {
    if (tableDict[slot][i] !== null && tableDict[slot][i].seats >= seats) {
      sortedTables.push([tableDict[slot][i]._id, tableDict[slot][i].seats]);
    }
  }

  sortedTables.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[1] - b[1];
  });

  var createReservation = function(tableId) {
    console.log("called function with id : " + tableId);
    Reservation.findOne({
        'restaurant': restaurant,
        'timeSlot.slot': slot,
        'timeSlot.table': tableId,
        'reservationDate': {
          '$gte': gteDate,
          '$lte': lteDate
        }
      })
      .then(reservation => {
        if (!reservation) {
          console.log("can create reservation with id: " + tableId);
          var timeSlot = [{
            'slot': slot,
            'table': tableId
          }];
          const newReservation = new Reservation({
            seats: seats,
            comment: comment,
            timeSlot: timeSlot,
            customer: customer,
            restaurant: restaurant,
            reservationDate: resDate
          });
          newReservation.save()
            .then(result => {
              res.send(result);
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
            });
        } else {
          console.log("reservation with id: " + tableId + " exists already.");
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  for (j = 0; j < sortedTables.length; j++) {
    var tableId = sortedTables[j][0];
    createReservation(tableId);
  }
});
```

Comment: It's odd that you create a throwaway date instance first to create `resDate` and then create the same instance for `queryDate`.... reverse these lines and you can reuse `queryDate` for both :)

Comment: Hi there. Just a few (hopefully helpful) suggestions. First, from your question it seems you could benefit from a bit of organization. Specifically, organize your thoughts into simple discrete problems and organize your questions around each one of those: I want to X; I've tried Y; I expected Z but experienced (not Z). Second, organize your code sample around that as well (see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Third, approach each problem in order and try to work your way through until you're absolutely stuck. Hope that helps!